# SQL command to copy values from one year to the next

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database consisting of EID of a person, Year and AWH amount of worked hours. How do I copy amount of worked hours of each person from 2018 to 2019?

I have this idea in my mind.

```
Insert into Hour (EID, YEAR, AWH)
    values (select distinct EID from Hour, 2019, AWH from Hour where Year=2018)
```

Thank you

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 0):

You want `insert . . . select`:

```
Insert into Hour (EID, YEAR, AWH)
    select distinct EID, 2019, AWH
    from Hour
    where Year = 2018;
```

I don't now if the `distinct` is necessary.  If not, you should remove it (it adversely affects performance).